# php post without form

Tags: php, refresh

I have a php page that takes some get strings, after some user interaction I want to continue executing some php code without navigating or refreshing the page so that its smooth and doesn't flicker. Ive tried secretly clicking invisible forms and it always refreshes, how can achieve this?

Also as a side note, I am using jquery but I was not able to get that post function up and running, I will keep trying it but let me know if that is a wrong solution.

```
//gallery.php 
//jquery
$(".download").click(function()
{
    $.post("gallery.php", { images: "testing it out" } );
});

<?php

if(isset($_POST['images']))
{
echo "It worked";
}
else if(isset($_GET['artist']))
{
echo "It worked2";
}

?>
```

They are both in the same page, the get always works because I pass the info though the url from another page. But the .download click doesnt cause the php code under post to execute

Comment: You don't need forms. Are you using a framework? Most frameworks have ajax functions. If not, check out `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: post your jQuery code so we can take a look

Answer (score 4):

Use Ajax to send a HTTP request in the background.

Answer (score 3):

Using Ajax is the solution...

You can try with jQuery, read this link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1):

jquery ajax is very simple method for post a form without page refresh ..

[read more about ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)?